# Warning the element position is invalid. Text being cropped in iReport Jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 4.5

[image: My report]

If you look at the image below, you will see a warning. The warning says:

> warning the element position is invalid

When I preview and export as pdf, then some of the text at the last block (bottom of the page) is getting cropped. I think it might have something to do with the band height, but I have adjusted it up, and it still doesn't work.

The text and style is embedded in a static text. If need be I can show some code.
I have also blacked out some information which is not needed.

I also sometimes get a warning:

> Element bottom reaches outside band area: y=1 height=543 band-height: 543

Comment: Some of your report's elements (or single element) has width or height greater than the container size (band in which it placed). Or the borders of element and the band are intersects

Comment: If you post the *jrxml* file it can be tested for sure

Comment: `When I preview and export as pdf, then some of the text at the last block (bottom of the page) is getting cropped` - Did you set *Stretch With Overflow* attribute?

Comment: The only property I can see with Strech it says: Relativ to band height/Relativ to Tallest object. I have tried both, and that didn't work. I can't find any `Strech With Overflow attribute`

Comment: I am using static text, and it seems Strech with overflow attribute is only for textfield

Comment: You can easily convert *staticText* to *textField*. But you can set the height of element as you want for static text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by adjusting the band height from the detail, then I made sure that band height from the text also matched the one from the detail. That seemed to do it.